# How to automate sending credentials to a DRM server to open a DRM pdf?

Tags: authentication, pdf, drm

I have a client who wants me to automate certain document processing work.

There is this pdf that can only be opened by sending in username and password to a DRM server.

When I open it using Acrobat, I see this.

[image]

I have the username and password, courtesy of the client.

Issue is how do I automate this?

I have done web scraping before, where I automate a web login so that I can execute certain routine tasks.

But this is the first time I am trying to automate an authentication that does not occur inside the browser.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: DRM solutions in this context are proprietary. Thus, you'll have to consult with the provider of this specific DRM solution.

Comment: There's an ethical & legal side to this. Doing what your client wants allows for them (and/or their employees etc.) to bypass the intended protection that the DRM stuff provides. Depending on your and/or your client's location that might be illegal. It's also likely that it will breach contractual stipulations your client most likely has with their provider(s). On top of that: it's ethically questionable to do this even if it's not illegal where you are and there are no contracts being violated.

Answer (score 1):

Companies pay a lot of money to do exactly not this. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/reader/topic_drm.html. I suspect the amount of effort to do this will not be worth it, especially if you are going to try and dive into the actual protocols/plugins used and hook in directly. This would be very implementations specific and likely to break in the future.

Your best bet is to leverage the existing Adobe Application and wrap it in an Automator script. Unfortunately, OSX specific.

They won't have generic workflow hooks, so the quick and nasty way would be to just record yourself doing it once, and play it back time and time again.

Workflow:

- Drag PDF onto custom app
- Automatically populate username
- Automatically populate password

If you are looking for somewhere to start: http://www.macosxautomation.com/automator/features/virtual-user.html

The DRM module itself can set permissions about how you can print and re-distribute the files itself, you won't be able to get around any of that, but assuming you have all the permissions set correctly, you should at least be able to automate opening the file itself on OSX.